# If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|x| - x \ne 0$, what do you know about $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a question on my math homework that I don't understand and would like some help on it.

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|x|-x \ne 0$, what do you know about $x$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you think of some examples of $x$ which do, or don't, have that property?

Comment: Think about what must be true if equality *does* hold

Answer (score 4):

You know $x \lt 0$, because if $x \ge 0$ then $|x| = x$.

Edit for clarity: by its nature, $|x| \ge 0$ and $|x| = 0$ if and only if $x =0$. This is known as positive-definiteness. Now, when is the line $y =x \ge 0$?

Here we have a comparison of the graphs $y=x$ and $y= |x|$, which are in red and blue, respectively.

When is the difference between them nonzero?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If its possible, can you share about how you reached that conclusion?

Comment: You missed an opportunity to teach a man to fish, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MPW I suppose so, but looks like I still might have something to do!

Comment: @David: you can edit your answer and show him how $|x|$ works.

Comment: @Laifcadio, by definition, for any $x\in\mathbb R$, $$|x| = \begin{cases}x, & \text{if }x \ge 0\\ -x, & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases}.$$ In other words, absolute value function leaves $x$ alone if $x$ is either positive or $0$ and changes $x$ to positive if negative. So, if $x$ is nonnegative (i.e., $x \ge 0$), then $|x| = x$ by the above, and so $$|x| - x = x - x = 0,$$which is NOT what we desired. However, if $x$ is negative, i.e., $x = -\alpha<0$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb R^+$(positive reals), then $$|x| - x = |-\alpha| - (-\alpha) = \alpha + \alpha = 2\alpha >0,$$ hence is nonzero as desired.

Comment: @Laifcadio I edited my post to be more instructive. Hope it helps!